# Is it possible that isFinishing() returns false in onPause() but returns true in onStop() ?

Tags: android

I am reading the book "Beginning Android Games,2nd Edition".

The page 129 says

'In onPause(), we simply pause our main loop thread, and if
Activity.isFinishing() returns true, we also save to disk any state we
want to persist.'

and the author does nothing in the onStop() method.

But the problem is that if isFinishing() returns false in onPause() but returns true in onStop(), we will lose unsaved data if we do not deal with onStop() method.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

If `isFinishing()` returned false in `onPause` it will also return false in `onStop` (and also in `onDestroy`).

I guess that an exception to this could be if you call `yourActivity.finish()` in the `onPause` method. If you do that, `isFinishing()` will return false before you call `yourActivity.finish()` and true after.

Answer (score 0):

If onStop() is called, onPause will also be called, and onDestroy() will call both.

There's a great diagram here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

that illustrates the Android activity lifecycle.